# Determine what year, month and day it will be on a certain week day in php

Tags: php, date

Let's say I want to get a have a database that contains days of the week. For example one record in database can contain a "Thursday". I want to be able to run my script anytime and determine what year, month and day will the next Thursday be each time I run my script. How can I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this:

```
$time = strtotime("next Thursday");
echo date("M d, Y", $time); // Echos "Nov 15, 2012"
```

Sample in action: http://codepad.org/NRm3xoJB